# How to create a new data frame

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Shape of passed values is (1000, 10), indices imply (1000, 11)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1))
scaled_features = scaler.transform(df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1))
df_feat = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features,columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error,

> Shape of passed values is (1000, 10), indices imply (1000, 11)

occurs on this line

```
df_feat = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features,columns=df.columns)
```

because `scaled_features` has 10 columns, but `df.columns` has length 11.

---

Notice that `df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1)` was called twice to drop the `TARGET CLASS` column from `df`. It seems likely that this is the extra column in `df` that you would want to drop from the list of new columns.

The problem can be fixed by saving a reference to `df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1)`
(let's call it `df_minus_target`), and passing `df_minus_target.columns` as the new list of columns:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
df_minus_target = df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1)
scaler.fit(df_minus_target)
scaled_features = scaler.transform(df_minus_target)
df_feat = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features,columns=df_minus_target.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about removing the last column from df when extracting columns to create `df_feat` dataframe (should be `pd.DataFrame(scaled_features,columns=df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1).columns)`, see the whole reproducible example below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Mock your dataset:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 10))
df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series([1, 1, 0, 0, 1], name='TARGET CLASS')], axis=1)

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1))
scaled_features = scaler.transform(df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1))
df_feat = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features,columns=df.drop('TARGET CLASS',axis=1).columns)

print(df_feat)
```

Or in order to prevent this kind of mistakes in the future - extract feature columns that you want to work on into a separate dataframe first:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# Mock your dataset:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 10))
df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series([1, 1, 0, 0, 1], name='TARGET CLASS')], axis=1)

# Extract raw features columns first.
df_feat = df.drop('TARGET CLASS', axis=1)

# Do transformations.
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(df_feat)
scaled_features = scaler.transform(df_feat)
df_feat_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features, columns=df_feat.columns)

print(df_feat_scaled)
```